explicit formula for some number theoretic functions
I was trying to calculate number of some 2 uniform tiling on torus using some elementary number theoretic method. On the way i need to know the values of the following two expression as a function of p and k.
$$g(p^k)=\sum_{i=\left\lceil k/2 \right\rceil}^k p^{2i-k},$$ and
$$f(p^k)=\sum_{i=\left\lceil k/2 \right\rceil}^k \#\{x \mid x(3x+2)\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{2i-k}}\}.$$
Can anyone give some suggestion for how to calculate these expressions?
Thanks in advance.

The first is simply a geometric sum that can be evaluated exactly. For the second, when $p\ne3$ it's impossible for $p$ to divide both $x$ and $3x+2$ simultaneously, so \begin{multline*}#{x\pmod{p^j}\colon x(3x+2)\equiv0\pmod{p^j}} \= #{x\pmod{p^j}\colon x\equiv0\pmod{p^j}} + #{x\pmod{p^j}\colon 3x+2\equiv0\pmod{p^j}},\end{multline*} which should simplify matters.
